# unicast traffic on windows server

Tags: networking, udp, multicast

I have three servers with IP addresses (10.15.23.23, 10.15.23.24, 10.15.23.25). Server 1 and Server 2 have Tomcat installed and are configured as a cluster listening on a multicast IP address (237.24.2.100). I'm seeing UDP traffic between servers 1 and 2 on the 3rd server which is a windows machine. That is when I run wireshark on the 3rd server, I see 1 and 2 talking. 
Is this okay? Will this cause any issues? I'm not an expert in networking.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this okay ?

Yes, almost certainly.

> Will this cause any issue ?

Who knows, there's nowhere near enough information here to say but given what you've said then I doubt this will cause an issue no.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is fine.  It indicates that whatever common segment to which they are connected is flooding traffic everywhere (and probably is a hub rather than a switch), or perhaps that it didn't have a complete MAC table to know where to direct the traffic at the time the packets were sent.  Unless you are using ethernet and you find you have saturation issues on the local network segment, you don't have a problem here.  If you do find that, get a better switch.